# How to get mediatype using diskpart using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to get mediatype of diskpart. I want to get the mediatype of the specific DeviceID.
I tried this way in my computer, It works, but I try from another computer, it return DeviceNumber is not found.

```
$DeviceID = "1"
$Get = Get-PhysicalDisk -DeviceNumber "$DeviceID"
$Get.MediaType
```

#### Updated

I use this way

```
$DeviceID = "1"
$Get = Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object -Property DeviceID
$MType = $Get[$DeviceID]
```

`Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, MediaType` gives this output:

```
DeviceID MediaType
-------- ---------
       2 HDD
       0 SSD
       1 SSD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$Get` contains a list of objects. The device ID is one property of those objects, and it can't be accessed via the index operator. `$DeviceID = "1"; $Get[$DeviceID]` will give you the 2nd item in the list `$Get`, not the item whose property `DeviceID` matches the value of the variable `$DeviceID`. Even if you sort the output of `Get-PhysicalDisk` you'd only ever get the desired object by coincidence, i.e. only if the device IDs are consecutive numbers starting at 0.

To get objects whose property `DeviceID` has a particular value use a `Where-Object` filter:

```
$DeviceID = 1
$disks = Get-PhysicalDisk
$MType = $disks |
         Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq $DeviceID } |
         Select-Object -Expand MediaType
```